# If a Jew owns a business advertising for a treatment but it is in fact not based on science, can a Jew or non-Jew report him to the authorities?

Tags: halacha

A man who says for example that he has treatment for psychological problems but there is in fact no evidence to call it treatment. Hence, should this man, who is taking tens if not hundreds of thousands of dollars under false pretenses, be reported to a gentile regulatory body?

Comment: Is he saying it's scientifically proven or just that it works? Does it actually work? Why wouldn't you go to bais din first and get permission to go to court? What would be the question in regards to a non jew? Are the people who he took the money from the ones who want to take him to court or others who want to prevent people from getting scammed? Is there any other way to prevent it without involving gentile regulatory agencies?

Comment: Anybody who is perpetrating evil should be reported to anyone you want to report them to. So for example, if I advertise a naturopathic cure for cancer and people do not take chemo because they believe I am better, and then they die, then I should be reported because I am a *rotzeach*.

Comment: You need to clarify your question.

Comment: If the said treatment is advertise as a bipolar treatment and the government has specific definitions and regulations as what can be advertised as psychotherapy, is this considered geneiva daat?

Comment: Extremely unlikely that someone would be able to make tens if not hundreds of thousands of dollars off  a treatment that isn't healing anyone. Even  if it is just  a placebo  effect he probably is healing at least SOME people if he is making so much

Comment: Well, homoeopathic medicine has no evidence base and people swear by it. That's why anecdotes are so flawed as evidence.

Comment: Also, people buy into clearly stupid things like Idolatrous faiths, e.g. Christianity, Mormonism and so on, believing that they are the "cure" to their life's problems. I wouldn't underestimate people's credulity

Comment: @KennyXiong it's not just other faiths such folly exists within our own circle, for example the cult leader eliezer berland was arrested for fraud (among other things including rape and capital murder): https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.haaretz.com/amp/jewish/.premium-associate-of-convicted-sex-offender-rabbi-berland-caught-on-tape-admitting-to-fraud-1.9352245 sadly this is a reality that preys on innocent and gullible people using spirituality and religion as a disguise

Answer (score 0):

I asked my Rav about this and he does not believe the person is misleading and deceptive in his business practice. He speaks about the early days of Kashrus in the city where there were many organizations offering different levels of kashrus. They were all kosher though some were more than others.

This also seem to parallel other medical practices in the community where alternative medicine is accepted.

I see the matter quite differently, however, since treatment to me only means evidence-based ones.